# Error merging multiple files within directory while skipping rows and columns

Tags: r, merge, syntax-error

I have multiple text files that I'm trying to merge together into one dataframe. 
Within each file I'm attempting to skip the first 10 rows, as well as the first column (there are 15 columns total, including the first one I'm trying to skip)
Here's code I'm currently using based on different pieces found online and on stack overflow:

```
for (x in list.files(pattern="*.txt", recursive=TRUE)) 
  {
  all_content <- readLines(x)
  skip = all_content[-c(1:10)]
  input <- read.table(textConnection(skip),
                      header = FALSE,
                      colClasses = c(rep("NULL", 1), 
                                     rep(NA, 14)),
                      sep="\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df <- rbind(df, input)
  }
```

However I'm getting the "Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'" error and I can't seem to figure out what's causing it. The code was working the last time I tried it...not sure if I accidentally changed something.

Thanks all.

Comment: it is occuring because you are trying to replicate a null value.

Comment: I’m not sure if that’s it. I recall having to include that line (from a different post on stack overflow) to force the first column (which includes data that’s I want to exclude) to be excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are trying to replicate null value, no matter how much you replicate null value it will be a single vector of Null value:

[image]
That's why it is showing error for closure object.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know what happens when you add this before your `for` loop.

```r
df <- NULL
```

Comment: I stand corrected. I'm assuming both Ayush and you are right. Could you please explain to me why adding this line made a difference? Thanks.
 #noobquestion

Comment: Glad that it helped! You were getting an error because of `rbind` statement wherein it couldn't understand how to interpret `df` in very first iteration of your `for` loop as `df` was not defined till this point.